# React-Datepicker: Using Moment creating a date range between a certain date to highlight dates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, momentjs, react-datepicker

I am using react-datepicker to highlight date ranges. I want to highlight every date after a certain date. It is using moment for its date. I have currently tried this.

```
highlightDates={[
   { "react-datepicker__day--highlighted-custom-1":
      [
         moment().add(moment(Date()).isAfter(Date()), 'days') 
      ]
   }
]}
```

Does anyone know how to get a duration of dates after a certain date in moment that goes on forever?

Comment: Do a greater than check. `If ( moment(Date()).isAfter(moment(), 'days') )` then add the day.

Comment: Im saying if I want to add all dates for a duration of today all the way through 5 years. Not just specific dates that fall after a given date but every day that falls after that day.